# Higher-order function data types in python

Tags: python, higher-order-functions, callable

I have to type hint this function
I understand that it takes a list and a function f. This is clear.
it takes the int in the list and does a "something with the function f and it appends to the string. But what goes into f: as type hint? Callable and then what?

```
def g(L: list[int], f: Callable[[], ]) -> str:
  result = ""
  for el in L:
    result+=f(el)
  return result
```

```
 Mypy output:

data_types_2.py:13: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("str" and "int")

        result+=f(el)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first list should be the types of the arguments to `f`; the last element should be its return type.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```
def g(L: list[int], f: Callable[[int], str]) -> str:
  result = ""
  for el in L:
    result+=f(el)
  return result
```